# regexp_replace in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to replace `E-*-[_]F*` string into `E-*-\_F*`. The code I am using is below.

```
select regexp_replace('E-*-[_]F*','-[\[(.)\]]', E'\\', 'g'); -- E-*\_]F*
```

I am not able to remove the closing bracket.

Comment: Your input and output are not clear.  Please show us some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you want the character inside the braces to be placed after a backslash:

```
jasen=#  select regexp_replace('E-*-[_]F*','-\[(.)\]', '\\\1', 'g');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 E-*\_F*
(1 row)
```

The pattern looks for any character `(.)` between `-[` and `]`
the parentheses make it remember the character.

The whole matched part is replaced with a backslash, represented by `\\` , followed by the first (and only) remembered part `\1`.

Comment: Thanks, @Jasen . This works. can you explain this a little?